# Does TFS API require Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, registry, tfs-sdk

I am trying to check in, check out, GetLatest, etc. with the TFS API using C#.
For the development PC and an Admin user this works flawlessly.
however, on a dedicated maschine without VS 2010 installed and the TFS user being a non-Admin this does nto work.
I get the following error:
*

> Access to the registry key
>   'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0' is denied.
>   2012-10-08 14:58:30 [...] error :    at
>   Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32 errorCode, String str)
>   at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.CreateSubKey(String subkey,
>   RegistryKeyPermissionCheck permissionCheck, RegistrySecurity
>   registrySecurity)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.UIHost.get_UserRegistryRoot()    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workstation.get_GetLatestOnCheckout()

*

I wonder if this has to do with Administrator rights?
The TFS "user" is actually a website running under that under account, so it is and is not supposed to be an Admin.

I tried running a test console app with my own credentials on the same maschine, and it works. So this is a credentials.

Can anyone help?
Is it enough to make the website user account an Admin?

**And: what does it want to access the registry when creating the local workspace?**

Comment: I've been able to do TFS work item API calls without visual studio. It might help if you show what kinds of operations cause this exception.

Comment: You answered yourself when you wrote it works with a console with your credentials. I dont know what iis version you are using, but by default the aspnet users/app pool users dont have access permissions to the registiry. you DONT have to turn the user into an admin, but simply add a read (write if needed) permissions for it to access to registry key.

Comment: Sounds like security/credential issue. What happens when you run web-site with your own credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've seen this kind of error when you are running a website under the application pool identity but the application pool identity is set to not load the user profile (and therefore has no HKCU registry access).

In IIS, under the advanced settings, set "Load User Profile"=True

See http://geekswithblogs.net/ProjectLawson/archive/2009/05/05/iis-system.web.aspnethostingpermission-exception-on-windows-7-rc.aspx

.. for more info.